# Spring Boot get istance of application.properties (or its file path)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am using spring boot and I need to get the instance of the application.properties file loaded at startup; is it possible?? (a possible workaround could be to find the file path of application.properties loaded at startup...but how can get it?)

currently I have an application.properies into my project but in future i have to get it from an environment variable that will contains the full path

the class that contains the management of my properties is like that:

```
@Component
public class SpringBootConfigurations {

public static String PROP_JIRA_USER;

@Value("${jira.user}")
private void setJiraUser(String user) {
    PROP_JIRA_USER = user;
}

public static String PROP_JIRA_PASSWORD;

@Value("${jira.password}")
private void setJiraPassword(String password) {
    PROP_JIRA_PASSWORD = password;
} etcc...
```

thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need to do that? It sounds like terrible design, and completely opposite to how Spring Boot behaves.

Comment: I need to send an email, and the function take in input a properties file that contains the smtp server parameters. this parameters are 7 and are noted in the .properties. Of course I could declare a new property and compose it with all the smtp parameter....but i was wondering if is possible to get the instance of properties file  loaded at startup

Comment: However kayaman, whats wrong exactly in the architecture in your opinion?(this is the first time that i use spring boot therefore I'm happy to take advice from more experienced people.)

Comment: you can create instance of propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer that would have all the properties loaded from application properties extending @propertyResource implementation in spring.

Comment: Do you mean you want to inject the whole property file into a `Properties` object? Because that can be done.

Comment: What exactly does your sendEmail method take as parameter? A File? Something else? Post the code. Can you change that method, or is it provided by an external library?

Comment: `function take in input a properties file that contains the smtp server parameters. this parameters are 7 and are noted in the .properties` this line from your comment is not clear to me. could you please elaborate it ?

Comment: Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
            }
        });

Comment: the "properties" is a Properties class and have to be set with 7 parameters usefull to configure the smtp server

Comment: Kayaman...i suppose that Spring at startup read the properties files....I'd like to get the instance of the file already loaded and pass it to my function

Comment: @rugby82 you don't really want the *file*, you want the information in the file. If your method (not function) takes a `File` as the parameter, you should refactor that method. If the method takes for example `Properties`, you should be injecting the contents of a (separate) property file into a `Properties` object.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need the properties as a java File object to match the signature of your SMTP library. One way to do that is to just read the properties as a classpath resource.

```
@Value("classpath:data/application.properites")
Resource resourceFile;
```

From there you can convert to a file with a `getFile` call and pass it to the library.

However, you may be better off creating a `ConfigurationProperties` object and just generating a file programmatically with a FileWriter and passing that along. It would be more declarative and clearer in the implementation exactly what is happening.

To add a bit more detail on Configuration properties. You could do something like this:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "smtp")
public class ConfigProperties {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private String username;
     // other smtp props
    // standard getters and setters

    public File propsAsFile() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("smtp.host", host);
        props.setProperty("smtp.port", port);
        ...
        File temp = File.createTempFile("xyz",".properties");
        FileOutputStream propsStream = new FileOutputStream(temp)
        prop.store(propsStream, null);
    } 
}
```

Also @Kayaman is correct in the comments. Only go through these file gymnastics if you absolutely need it (seems unlikely that you need all of this but depends on the library you're using)

For more on ConfigurationProperties
https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot

Comment: mmhh...could be a feasible work around....I suppose that the resourceFile will contains the file path of my properties file; isn't true?

Comment: You can turn `resourceFile` directly into a java `File` object. You don't need to know the actual path. Then you can pass that as an argument to your SMTP library. If you post the method signature of the library you need to call i'll write an example in the answer.

Comment: What happens if the applications wants to load a profile (i.e. application-dev.properties)?

Comment: @BeppeC In that cases I'd use the ConfigurationProperties approach which is probably the better of the two choices anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Spring (Boot) offers a very comprehensive and flexible configuration mechanism that abstracts from the source of configuration. This mechanism is based on a well defined property override order that is specified in [Chapter 2: Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config).

Considering this documentation, there are several ways how you could get your configuration parameters into your Spring Boot application (non-exhaustive):

1. Pass them as command line argument (e.g. `--smpt.port=1234`)
2. Pass them as System Properties in the command line (e.g. `-Dsmpt.port=1234`)
3. Define them as environment variables
4. Use [`@PropertySource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html) annotation on your `@Configuration` classes. As the `@PropertySource` value can contain `${...}` placeholders, it should be possible to use an environment variable here to refer to your properties file.
5. Write your own [`PropertySource`-implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertySource.html). (Although I think that's not necessary for your purposes.)

See also https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring.